# Get wishlist count for my published product using steamworks API

Tags: steam, steam-web-api, steamworks-api

I'm the publisher of a game on steam.

The goal here is to get data over time on the wishlist count for our product that can be shown in a custom dashboard that aggregates other data eg youtube views, etc.

On the partner page for my game it lists the # of people who have wishlisted my game.

Is there a way to get that data via API?